# How can I filter in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm using vue.js in my project and I need to filter this json in my html and display only what is with `areas = area_one`, I am currently using one filter, but it displays all the elements of my json

JSON

```
   {
      "ID":789,
      "title":"Title Page",
      "image_desktop":"image21.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image234.jpg",
      "link":"#",
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":765,
      "title":"Title Page 2",
      "image_desktop":"image231.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image421.jpg",
      "link":"#\/link",
      "areas":[
         "area_two"
      ]
   }
]
```

and vue HTML

```
   <div v-for="example in filtered_examples" :key="example.ID">
      <img :src="example.image_mobile">
      <img :src="example.image_desktop">
    </div>
```

I need to filter only one of the areas in my html

The filtered_example:

```
  this.filtered_examples = !this.area ? this.examples : this.examples.filter(b => b.areas.indexOf(this.area) > -1 )
```

Comment: where's the `filtered_examples` code ?

Comment: the output of your question is ambiguous, plz mention what should be the output so it will be easy to understand.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I put in my example! Thanks

Comment: @Dcoder
I need to filter through this array
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]

Comment: @CodeG It's working well, I just tested with your data and your `filter` statement. Check  `this.area` value.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos 
I'm not able to filter through the array of areas, the filter is showing all

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```js
var examples = [{
    "ID": 789,
    "title": "Title Page",
    "image_desktop": "image21.jpg",
    "image_mobile": "image234.jpg",
    "link": "#",
    "areas": [
      "area_one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 765,
    "title": "Title Page 2",
    "image_desktop": "image231.jpg",
    "image_mobile": "image421.jpg",
    "link": "#\/link",
    "areas": [
      "area_two"
    ]
  }
];
var area = 'area_one';
var filtered_examples = examples.filter(b => b.areas.indexOf(area) > -1);
console.log(filtered_examples);
```